# Dapper mapping String parameter as AnsiString

Tags: c#, ado, dapper, interbase

I need to pass parameters to SQL statement, with Firebird ADO everything works well, but with InterBase ADO there is a problem. 
My code:

```
result = conn.Query<DestClass>(sqlCmd, new
{
  stringParam = stringVal,
  intParam1 = intVal1,
  intParam2 = intVal2
}).Single();
```

With that I've got `FormatException`, but when I define parameters with `DynamicParameters` and setting `DbType.AnsiString` for stringParam, SQL works well. But I've got many places in my code when I need to pass string and I don't want to change this in all places.

Then I found that I can use `Dapper.SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(String), DbType.AnsiString);`
but I can't. I've got `Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.`

How to resolve this issue?

**EDIT**

It looks like problem is solved in Dapper v1.22.

Answer (score 3):

There is a proposal to add an assembly-level attribute of the form:

```
[assembly:SomeName(blah)]
```

that would control the *default* string type for all types coming from that assembly. This would probably achieve most of what you need (although it would push the swing the other way, so you need to tell the *other* uses what to do). I am currently very actively hacking dapper, so I would expect this to materialize in the short term.

Note that you do not need to use `DynamicParameters`; you can also use:

```
stringParam = new DbString { Value = stringVal, IsAnsi = true }
```

Comment: Interesting proposal, but my gut reaction is to be uncomfortable with the idea of an API who's behavior depends on an attribute in the calling assembly. What about performance, inlining and maintainability (specifically the fact that behavior could change by moving a class into a different assembly)?

Comment: @Joe il-merge would indeed complicate things

Comment: Thanks for response, but `stringParam = new DbString { Value = stringVal, IsAnsi = true }` is not working. Only when I pass parameters with `DynamicParameters` it works fine. Could you explan to me how should I use `[assembly:SomeName(blah)]`?

Comment: @MarekRuszczyk to emphasize: that is simply a proposal at this point. For you to use that, *I need to write the code*. I will check on the dbstring, though - that should work.

Comment: @MarekRuszczyk this works fine: http://pastie.org/9158605 - can you be more specific about the scenario that isn't working?

Comment: @MarcGravell, Ok, I'm using Embarcadero Interbase ADO v.16, and here's my tests: http://pastebin.com/UsLg6Y4r, http://pastebin.com/vc5rwghV - Exception "input string was not in a correct format". But http://pastebin.com/y8qzyzb4 working good. Is that enough? I don't know how to describe it more specific, It is simple query.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I see that there is a new version 1.22 (I was using 1.13), and it's look's like my problem is solved. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @MarcGravell Where is this documented?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski which "this" specifically?

Comment: How to solve your problem?  Is it just AddTypeMap?  Where is AddTypeMap documented?  What other settings are possible with it?  Does it matter if it is a `string` vs. `string?`? What about `char` and `char?`?